# How to Save a Duration in a plist?

Tags: ios, nsdate, plist

How can I save a duration in a plist so that I can load up some sample data in Core Data?

By duration I mean a task has a time duration. Could be 1h12m. Could be 15m.

Using this category

```
+(NSDate *)dateWithHour:(NSInteger)hour minute:(NSInteger)minute
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    components.hour = hour;
    components.minute = minute;
    NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [calender dateFromComponents:components];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSLog(@"**Date Utils** %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    return date;
}
```

I can create a duration of 15minutes

```
 task.duration = [NSDate dateWithHour:0 minute:15];
```

It outputs to the console as:

```
0001-01-01 04:29:24 +0000
```

Which doesn't appear to be 15minutes. It looks like 4h29m24s. If I run the date back through a dateFormatter sure enough it prints out 15m.
How can I input a time duration in the plist as shown below?

[image: plist]

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Time and duration are different. How does the example show duration? All I see is a date. Not sure if NSDate is the right object to store a duration. You should probably just use an int and count the duration in seconds.

Comment: The example doesn't show a duration. I'm wanting to represent a duration with an NSDate since I've had some success doing that in code but also need to do it in a plist that i create dummy data using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are terribly complicated because of time zones and leap years and leap seconds and so on. They're not suitable for this use case and you will have all kinds of bugs trying to use them.

The correct data type for durations is NSTimeInterval, which is a 64 bit floating point number, in seconds. NSDate uses this data type internally as well.

The easiest way to create a time interval is:

```
NSDate *aDate = ...
NSDate *anotherDate = ...
NSTimeInterval duration = [aDate timeIntervalSinceDate:anotherDate];
```

And you'd save it to a plist with NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *durationNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];
```

Note that NSTimeInterval is actually a double.